# Laravel Input::get() is not working via ajax request on Ubuntu server

Tags: ajax, ubuntu, laravel

I have problems with dealing ajax requests on my server.

I have this ajax request from `js`:

```
$.get('/fetchEntries',{id:id},function(data){
 if(data){
  alert('success');
 }else{
  alert('failed);
 }
});
```

On my `routes` I got:

```
Route::get('/fetchEntries','EntriesController@fetchEntries');
```

My controller had:

```
public function fetchEntries(){
        if(Request::ajax()){
            $id= Input::get('id');
            dd($id);
        return Response::json($id);
        }
    }
```

This code is fully functional on my development machine in Windows and alerts 'success'.
But on my deployment server (Ubuntu) it alerts 'failed' which means it did not fetch any data. When I tried to debug the file on the server putting `dd(Input::get('id));` or `dd($id)` these return `NULL` value even if I have the right path on `inspect element>Network` tab with `fetchEntries?id=1`.

I was really confused with this. It works fine on my Windows machine but on my server it doesn't.

Comment: if you have dd (die and dump) you are telling the server to stop processing and dump the variable.  You can't do that to begin with because you'll never get the response because the server will never hit the return part of the function.  If you want to troubleshoot anything you'll have to do that in your jquery by logging the data.

Comment: i know.. that's why i said when i want to debug it i put `dd()`. the problem occurs before i debug it with `dd()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Route::get('/fetchEntries/{data}','EntriesController@fetchEntries');

public function fetchEntries($data=NULL){

        if(Request::ajax()){

            $id= $data;
            dd($id);
        return Response::json($id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue lies on your .htaccess file on the server. The RewriteRule is not properly done.
Find the similar line and fix as follows.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA]
```

[QSA] is the changes section